# how to customise sw.js to return errors

Tags: vaadin, service-worker, vaadin24

Vaadin 24.

We are implementing a client-side error handling system that sends any client-side errors to the server.

We have this working fine with the required hooks created in our index.html.

Our problem is with the service worker (sw.js).

Vaadin is generating the sw.js file but we need to modify it.

Is there a standard technique for customising the sw.js file?

Are there are standard techniques for catching errors in sw.js?

Here is an example error from sw.js that we would like to catch (yes I know this indicates a separate problem).

```
sw.js:1 Uncaught (in promise) bad-precaching-response: bad-precaching-response :: [{"url":"https://xxx/VAADIN/build/component-picker-acd91974.js","status":404}]
    at d._handleInstall (https://xxx/sw.js:1:8531)
    at async d._handle (https://xxx/sw.js:1:7942)
    at async d._getResponse (https://xxx/sw.js:1:7010)
```